# WSL idle error ,(python)

Tags: idle, idle-python

When running the command `idle` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/idle", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 1483, in main
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2270, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: Have you installed an X server? See for example [Cannot run Spyder on Ubuntu (windows bash)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392553/cannot-run-spyder-on-ubuntu-windows-bash)

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks